# License related issue in NSIS Script

Tags: nsis

I want to add a license page in my installer actually i wrote a script like this

```
; License page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "$INSTDIR\LICENSE.rtf"

Section ""
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
; Put file there
File "LICENSE.rtf"
```

But while compiling i am getting this issue.

```
LicenseData: open failed "$INSTDIR\LICENSE.rtf"
```

please let me know where to place the License.rtf file for access

Answer (score 2):

For compiling you should give path of licence file where it is actually present when you are  compiling.

Comment: Use !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "LICENSE.rtf" if license is stored in the same directory as script.